# Odd characters returned when using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm using cURL to download content on different pages. Some of them returns odd characters like �. What am I doing wrong? Posting my code below:

```
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.centernail.se/');
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING , '');
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.165 Safari/535.19');
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: it seems they are not using utf-8 encoding - I guess it's latin-swedish or similar

Answer (score 2):

It means you are not handling encodings. A page is encoded using a certain encoding. You or the browser you're outputting it into or whatever you are looking at that downloaded page with is interpreting it using a certain encoding. If the two don't match, you get wrongly interpreted characters. It's that simple.

You are deciding what encoding you interpret the data with. You need to make sure the data you're outputting matches that encoding. The best is to use UTF-8, and inspect the HTTP headers or HTML meta headers of the page (in that order) to figure out what encoding it is in, then convert it to UTF-8 if it's something else.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Answer (score 0):

convert the encoding of the result or change the encoding of the output

- to convert try [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) php function
- to change the output change [character encoding of html](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)